# Overlaying an image with a movable disk that can be resized

Tags: manipulate, locator

I'm trying to create this:

1. A map with a PNG picture in the background
2. A locator for position
3. The locator (p1) needs to have a disk with center in p1

The problem is that the locator disk and the map can coexist together, I tried `ImageCompose`, `Overlay`, `Show`... "p1" update good but the disk doesn't move!

```
size = 6000;
escala = 1000;
proporcion = size/escala;
r = 100;

With[{source = ImageResize[Import["LINK.png"], {escala}]},
  Manipulate[
    Image[source, ImageSize -> escala],
    {{pt, {escala/2, escala/2}}, ControlType -> Locator},
    Row[
      {Style["Posición = ", Bold, 15], 
       Dynamic @ Style[{Dynamic[proporcion pt[[1]]] , 
       Dynamic[proporcion (escala - pt[[2]])]}, Bold, 25]}],
    ControlPlacement -> Top, 
    TrackedSymbols -> {pt}]
```

The map is 6000 x 6000 and the "Position" coordinates have to be in this range. I want to see the image in the CDF so I use `With`.

When I try to add a `Graphic[Disk[p1]]`, the disk doesn't move in any way, I want to see that disk moving around the image with and control its radius.

This is the easiest way that I see to create my map. I can't use a map from the Geographic module because they are all real-life maps. I want a fantasy map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code that solves your moving disk problem.

```
With[
   {source = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}],
    disk = 
      Graphics[{White, Opacity[.4], EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.05]]}]},
  Manipulate[
    source,
    {{pt, ImageDimensions[source]/2}, Appearance -> disk, ControlType -> Locator},
    Dynamic @ 
      Row[{Style["Posición = ", Bold, 15], Style[{pt[[1]], pt[[2]]}, Bold, 25]}],
    ControlPlacement -> Top,
    TrackedSymbols -> {pt}]]
```

[image: lena]

#### Update

To be able to adjust the radius of disk, a somewhat different approach must taken. Injecting the disk into the code with `With` must be abandoned because that produces a static, fixed-size disk. Instead I will define a function in which the disk is expressed as a function of its radius and call it with the dynamic variable associated with a control.

```
With[{source = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]},
  With[{dimensions = ImageDimensions[source]},
    Manipulate[
      source,
      {{r, .05, Style["r", Bold, 15]}, .02, .5, .01, ImageSize -> 500},
      {{pt, dimensions/2}, Locator, Appearance -> disk[r]}, 
      Dynamic @ 
        Row[{Style["Posición = ", Bold, 15], Style[{pt[[1]], pt[[2]]}, Bold, 15]}], 
      ControlPlacement -> Top,
      Initialization :> (
        disk[r_] :=
          Graphics[
            {White, Opacity[.4], EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, ImageScaled[r]]},
            ImageSize -> dimensions])]]]
```

[image: lena-update]

Comment: I like it but i can't control the radius!

I would like to change the radius between 1 and 512 (the picture of the example is 512x512), i know how to create the slider itself the i can't introduce "r" in Disk[] like this:

    Disk[{0,0},r]

Comment: Thanks! it was so useful to me. I like it!

Can i add the position over the disk? (not inside, over) to avoid the label with the "{ }" because it doesn't look good at all.

Comment: @ShiroIgnis You say you like my answer. If so, you should accept it. But all you do, is ask for more help. For your latest request, here's a hint: `disk` makes a graphics object. That object can contain text like any other graphics object. You will have to add an argument to `disk` to pass in the coordinates. It would be good practice for you to work this out on own from this hint. If you are not up to it, you should ask about it in a new question.

Comment: Ok, i didn't know about "accept the answer", I appologise, I checked the answer.

It's enough for me =) i will continue by me own since this point, thanks again.