# References in the map + References in a Locator

Tags: graphics, manipulate, gui-construction, locator

```
With[{source = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]}, 
  With[{dimensions = ImageDimensions[source]},
    n = 10;
    sub = Subdivide[-1, 1, n];
    grid = 
      Graphics[{}, 
        GridLines -> {sub, sub}, 
        PlotRangePadding -> None, 
        GridLinesStyle -> Directive[White, Thick], 
        ImageSize -> ImageDimensions @ source];
    Manipulate[
      Overlay[{source, grid}],
      {{r, .05,Style["r", Bold, 15]}, .02, .5, .01, ImageSize -> 500}, 
      {{pt, dimensions/2},  Locator,  Appearance -> disk[r]}, 
      Dynamic @ 
        Row[{Style["Posición = ", Bold, 15], Style[{pt[[1]], pt[[2]]}, Bold, 15]}], 
     ControlPlacement -> Top, 
     Initialization :> (
        disk[r_] := 
          Graphics[
            {White, Opacity[.4], EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, ImageScaled[r]]}, 
     ImageSize -> dimensions])]]]
```

1) I am trying to add a 3rd option:

```
Overlay[{source, grid, text}],
```

Where `text` has to be a lot of references with a static positions over the image.

I tried with:

```
text = Graphics[{}, Text["Reference1"], {p1x, p1y}];
```

But it doesn't work! the text appears anywhere!

In this case "Reference1" is the name of a city or place. It has to be static even if I change the scale of the image.

2) I tried to change this too:

```
{{pt0, {dimensions[[1]], dimensions[[2]]}}, Locator, 
 Appearance -> disk[(r0/dimensions)/proporcion, White]},
```

I want to see the coordinates over the locator disk. I tried to add `Text` inside the `Disk`, outside, and even in the locator itself but it doesn't work.

I saw too that the text can be add inside the `Disk` but I think that `Appearance` doesn't support it.

In this case "Reference" is the coordinate of the `Locator`.

EDIT: (with Answer 1)

My code has 4 disk:

```
{{pt0, {dimensions[[1]] (0.51), dimensions[[2]] (0.525)}}, Locator,  Appearance -> disk[(r0/dimensions)/proporcion, White, pt0]},

{{pt1, {dimensions[[1]] (0.59), dimensions[[2]] (0.6)}}, Locator,  Appearance -> disk[(r1/dimensions)/proporcion, Red, pt1]},

{{pt2, {dimensions[[1]] (0.465), dimensions[[2]] (0.47)}}, Locator,  Appearance -> disk[(r2/dimensions)/proporcion, Green, pt2]},

{{pt3, {dimensions[[1]] (0.44), dimensions[[2]] (0.6)}}, Locator,  Appearance -> disk[(r3/dimensions)/proporcion, Blue, pt3]},
```

And I introduced a change (for color):

```
 Initialization -> ( 
 disk[r_, color_, pt_] := 
  Graphics[{{Opacity[.4, color], EdgeForm[Black], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[r]]}, {Thick, 
     Line[{Scaled@{.5 - r/8, .5}, Scaled@{.5 + r/8, .5}}], 
     Line[{Scaled@{.5, .5 - r/8}, Scaled@{.5, .5 + r/8}}]}, {Text[
      Framed[Style[Row[pt, ","], Bold, 12], FrameMargins -> Tiny, 
       Background -> Opacity[.4, White]], Scaled@{.5, .52 + r}]}},
    ImageSize -> dimensions])]]]
```

Before:

```
 Initialization -> (disk[r_, color_, pt_] := 
  Graphics[{color, Opacity[.4], EdgeForm[Black], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, ImageScaled[r]]}, ImageSize -> dimensions])]]]
```

With the 1st initialization each disk creates a gigant red square and no text.

I correct it like this:

```
Initialization -> ( 
 disk[r_, color_, pt_] := 
  Graphics[{{Opacity[.4, color], EdgeForm[Black], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[r]]}, {Thick(*,Line[{Scaled@{.5-r/8,.5},
     Scaled@{.5+r/8,.5}}],Line[{Scaled@{.5,.5-r/8},Scaled@{.5,.5+
     r/8}}]*)}, {Text[
      Framed[Style[Row[pt, ","], Bold, 12], FrameMargins -> Tiny ,
        Background -> Opacity[.4, White]](*,Scaled@{.5,.52+
      r}*)]}}, ImageSize -> dimensions])]]]
```

All the commented code brokes the program itself.

Anyway to "move" the label over the disk? not inside.

Comment: Ok i edited it.

Comment: I am tempted to revise the title to "Trouble with modifying other people's code"/

Comment: Related questions: [concerning grid overlay](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132085/3066) and [concerning moving disk](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132075/3066).

Comment: What is the problem with uses "other people's code"? it hasn't an owner =P

I'm trying to add more things over it, i reduced all that i could to make the question itself.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with using code posted in answers. It is put into the answer to be used by others. However, it is good practice as well as good manners to give a reference to the source when you present the code in another question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, i didn't know about this "honor code" here, i appologise.

I added two links at the beggining, It is like a "quote" I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

I see you were not up to working up the hint I gave you in a comment to my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132091/3066). So is here how a coordinates callout can be added to the moving disk. I throw in a cross-hair for free.

```
With[{source = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]}, 
  With[{dimensions = ImageDimensions[source]},
    Manipulate[
      source,
      {{r, .05, Style["r", Bold, 15]}, .02, .5, .01, ImageSize -> 500}, 
      {{pt, dimensions/2}, Locator, Appearance -> disk[r, pt]},
      ControlPlacement -> Top,
      Initialization :> (
        disk[r_, pt_] :=
          Graphics[
            {{Opacity[.4, White], EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[r]]},
            {Thick,
               Line[{Scaled @ {.5 - r/8, .5}, Scaled @ {.5 + r/8, .5}}], 
               Line[{Scaled @ {.5, .5 - r/8}, Scaled @ {.5, .5 + r/8}}]},
            {Text[
               Framed[
                 Style[Row[pt, ","], Bold, 12],
                 FrameMargins -> Tiny,
                 Background -> Opacity[.4, White]],
               Scaled @ {.5, .52 + r}]}},
            ImageSize -> dimensions])]]]
```

[image: lena]

Comment: I tryed but I failed T.T so I answered again.

Well, your code solutions question number 2 =) thanks!

Comment: @ShiroIgnis Thanks but no up-vote? I rather have the up-vote.

Comment: It didn't work in my main code T.T  i was testing it 1st